Propensity score matching - How to select observation for matching among repeated measures
I am unsure how to resolve the following problem and am hoping someone might have a suggestion.
We have repeated measures data for MS patients and we want to look at potential differences in an outcome of interest among those MS patients who are diagnosed with cancer (exposure) and a comparable group who aren't (from a linked dataset).
We would like to match on some 'baseline' variables to use in a time-to-event analysis. Ideally we would like to use age (at cancer diagnosis) as the baseline. In the cancer group, this is fairly simple as we can just filter the observation from our MS dataset that has the closest age to that at cancer diagnosis.
But this is obviously problematic when it comes to choosing a baseline observation using age for our non-cancer cohort as they don't have a reference age value (as they don't have cancer). And it doesn't really make sense to just say select the observation closest to 50, or 60, because cancer can really occur at any age.
Is there a way that people would approach this problem for selecting among repeated measures of 'control' observations? Or is this an impasse?
Thanks
